# I cant figure out how to get my JCombox's to insert their data into my database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

please help me i cant figure out to get my State ComboBox data to insert into my database here is my code. If anyone can help me id really appreciate it because it is driving me crazy that i cant figure it out.

```
    import java.awt.*;

    import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
    import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
    import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;

    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.sql.Connection;

    import javax.swing.Box;

    import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

    import java.sql.*;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

    import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;


    public class Form1 extends JInternalFrame {
    private JButton btnSubmit;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_4;

    private Cancel form3;
    private JTextField textField_5;
    private JTextField textField_6;
    private JTextField textField_7;
    private JTextField textField_8;
    private JTextField textField_9;
    private JComboBox statesComboBox;
    private JComboBox comboBox;
    private JDateChooser Date;



    Connection con = null;

    /*public void fillComboBox(){
        try{
            String query= "insert into Oilform2 (State,OilType) values(?,?)";
            java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs= pst.executeQuery();



            while (rs.next()){
                statesComboBox.addItem(rs.getString("State"));
                comboBox.addItem(rs.getString("OilType"));
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    */

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Form1() {
        con = database.dbConnector();
        setTitle("New Customer");
        setIconifiable(true);
        setClosable(true);
        setBounds(-10, -10, 600, 450);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(panel_1, Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 505, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(panel, Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 505, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 235, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(panel_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 56, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try{
                String query = "insert into Oilform2 (FirstName, LastName, table1col, StreetAddress, City, Make, Model, CarYear, PhoneNumber, Mileage, State, OilType) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    java.sql.PreparedStatement pst= con.prepareStatement(query);


                    pst.setString(1, textField.getText());
                    pst.setString(2, textField_1.getText());
                    pst.setString(3, textField_2.getText());
                    pst.setString(4, textField_3.getText());
                    pst.setString(5, textField_4.getText());
                    //Combo Boxes States
                    //String value=statesComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    //pst.setString(6, value);
                    //pst.setString(6, (String)statesComboBox.getSelectedItem());

                    pst.setString(6, textField_5.getText());
                    pst.setString(7, textField_6.getText());
                    pst.setString(8, textField_7.getText());
                    pst.setString(9, textField_8.getText());
                    pst.setString(10,textField_9.getText());




                    //pst.setString(13, (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem());
                    //Combo Boxes Oil Types
                    //String value1=comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    //pst.setString(13, value1);



                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");

                    pst.execute();





                }catch(Exception i) {
                        System.err.println("Exception: " + i.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            });

        // Quit
        JButton btnQuit = new JButton("Quit");
        btnQuit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });


        GroupLayout gl_panel_1 = new GroupLayout(panel_1);
        gl_panel_1.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_panel_1.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel_1.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(148)
                    .addComponent(btnSubmit)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(btnQuit)
                    .addContainerGap(147, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_panel_1.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_panel_1.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, gl_panel_1.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel_1.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btnSubmit)
                        .addComponent(btnQuit))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        panel_1.setLayout(gl_panel_1);
        //----------------------------------------------------

        JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last Name:");
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);
        //----------------------------------------------------

        JLabel lblMi = new JLabel("MI:");
        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        //----------------------------------------------------

        JLabel lblFirstName = new JLabel("First Name:");
        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        //----------------------------------------------------

        JLabel lblStreetAddress = new JLabel("Street Address");

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setColumns(10);
        //----------------------------------------------------

        String[] statesStrings = { "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA",
                "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME","MD", "MA", "MI", "MN",
                "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK",
                "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"};

        JComboBox statesComboBox = new JComboBox(statesStrings);
        statesComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        //states.addActionListener(this);
        //----------------------------------------------------

        JLabel lblState = new JLabel("State");
        //----------------------------------------------------

        JLabel lblCity = new JLabel("City");

        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setColumns(10);
        //----------------------------------------------------

        JLabel lblMake = new JLabel("Make");

        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.setColumns(10);
        //----------------------------------------------------

        JLabel lblModel = new JLabel("Model");

        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.setColumns(10);

        //----------------------------------------------------
        JLabel lblYear = new JLabel("Year");

        textField_7 = new JTextField();
        textField_7.setColumns(10);

        //----------------------------------------------------
        JLabel lblNumber = new JLabel("Phone Number");

        textField_8 = new JTextField();
        textField_8.setColumns(10);

        //----------------------------------------------------
        JLabel lblMileage = new JLabel("Mileage");

        textField_9 = new JTextField();
        textField_9.setColumns(10);
        //----------------------------------------------------

        JLabel lblOilType = new JLabel("Oil Type");

        String[] oilTypes = { "Oil Type 1", "Oil Type 2", "Oil Type 3", "Oil Type 4"};

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(oilTypes);
         comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JLabel lblDate = new JLabel("Date:");

        JDateChooser Date = new JDateChooser();
        Date.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        //----------------------------------------------------
        GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(panel);
        gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(lblLastName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblStreetAddress))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 141, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(lblMi)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(lblFirstName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(textField_2, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 139, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(textField_3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(lblCity)
                                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(textField_4, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 152, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addGap(18))
                                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(lblYear)
                                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)))
                                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(textField_7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(lblState)
                                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(statesComboBox, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))))
                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(lblMake)
                                        .addComponent(lblNumber))
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(textField_8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(textField_5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addGap(18)
                                            .addComponent(lblModel))))
                                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(lblOilType)
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(comboBox, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(textField_6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                                        .addComponent(lblDate)
                                        .addComponent(lblMileage))
                                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                        .addComponent(Date, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(textField_9))))
                            .addGap(70)))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblLastName)
                        .addComponent(lblMi)
                        .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(textField_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblFirstName))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblStreetAddress)
                        .addComponent(textField_3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(statesComboBox, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblState)
                        .addComponent(lblCity)
                        .addComponent(textField_4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(textField_5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblMake)
                        .addComponent(textField_7, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblYear)
                        .addComponent(textField_6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblModel))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblNumber)
                        .addComponent(textField_8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblMileage)
                        .addComponent(textField_9, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(lblOilType)
                            .addComponent(comboBox, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(lblDate))
                        .addComponent(Date, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addContainerGap(53, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        panel.setLayout(gl_panel);
        getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shadowing you variables...

You declare `statesComboBox` as an instance field in your class...

```
private JComboBox statesComboBox;
```

But when you initalise it within your constructor, you declare it as a local variable...

```
JComboBox statesComboBox = new JComboBox(statesStrings);
```

This means you `ActionListener` is trying to use a `null` references (the instance field)

Comment: So do i need to change it to public instead of Private?

Comment: You need to remove the re-declaration and initialise the class instance field

Comment: Can you show me by any chance like the code of how it should look like? Because im a little confused

Comment: Instead of `JComboBox statesComboBox = new JComboBox(statesStrings);` it should be `statesComboBox = new JComboBox(statesStrings);`

Comment: You are declaring two variables with the same name, one is globally accessible within the class, one is locally accessible from within the constructor.  You `ActionListener` is using the global variable, which is never initialised